# How Administrator can determine user permissions Spring

Tags: spring, permissions, spring-security, authorization, administrator

I have a web application which has 2 actors:

`superAdmin & admin`

The superAdmin can determine all permissions of admin(eg: admin will use "add" methode and won't use "delete")
SuperAdmin can change permissions for Admin in the web page (not the programmer)
So how can i do that? if someone can just tell me the big lines to follow.
PS: I'm using Spring MVC + Spring security+hibernate+jsp

Comment: Please mention what have you already tried?

Comment: i didn't try anything.That is new for me

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring security you can add the paths and user access to them

```
     <intercept-url pattern="/add.do" access="superAdmin, admin"/>
     <intercept-url pattern="/delete.do" access="superAdmin"/>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But it seems that you have not understood me. SuperAdmin can change permissions for Admin in the web page (not the programmer)